# How to get the right values when I convert hex to ascii character

Tags: node.js, hex, ascii, non-ascii-characters, extended-ascii

I'm trying to convert a hexa file to text, using javascript node js.

```
function hex_to_ascii(str1){
    var hex  = str1.toString();
    var str = '';
    for (var n = 0; n < hex.length; n += 2) {
        str += String.fromCharCode(parseInt(hex.substr(n, 2), 16));
    }
    return str;
}
```

I have a problem concening the extended ASCII charaters, so for example when I try to convert 93 I've get Â“ instead of ô and when I convert FF I've get Ã¿ instead of (nbsp) space.

I want to get the same extended charaters as this table: https://www.rapidtables.com/code/text/ascii-table.html

Answer (score 0):

This problem is slightly more complex than it seems at first, since you need to specify an encoding when converting from extended ascii to a string. For example Windows-1252, ISO-8859-1 etc. Since you wish to use the linked table, I'm assuming you wish to use [CP437](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_page_437) encoding.

To convert a buffer to string you need a module that will do this for you, converting from a buffer (in a given encoding) to string is not trivial unless the buffer is in a natively supported node.js encoding, e.g. UTF-8, ASCII (7-bit only!), Latin1 etc.

I would suggest using the [iconv-lite](https://www.npmjs.com/package/iconv-lite) package, this will convert many types of encoding. Once this is installed the code should look as follows (this takes each character from 0x00 to 0xFF and prints the encoded character):

```
const iconv = require('iconv-lite');

function hex_to_ascii(hexData, encoding) {
    const buffer = Buffer.from(hexData, "hex");
    return iconv.decode(buffer, encoding);
}

const testInputs = [...Array(256).keys()];
const encoding = "CP437";
console.log("Decimal\tHex\tCharacter")
for(let input of testInputs) {
    console.log([input, input.toString(16), hex_to_ascii(input.toString(16), encoding)].join("\t"));
}
```

Comment: @Lennox I've get an error Error: Cannot find module 'iconv' . despite that I installed iconv using npm install iconv

Comment: Oh dear, I suspect there's an install issue, well let's try using iconv-lite instead, this might install without problems. I will update my answer to use this package instead! Thank you for trying my answer.. I hope the updated one works better!